# Dynamic class loading (java 11)

Tags: java, java-11

I have the following code

```
ClassLoader classLoader = IFileTransferClient.class.getClassLoader();
Class f_t_c = classLoader.loadClass(fileGroupConfig.getFileTransferClientClassName());
fileTransferClient = (IFileTransferClient) f_t_c.newInstance();
```

The compiler (Java 11) is complaining that `newInstance` is deprecated.

How does one convert the above code for Java 11 compiler?

Comment: javadoc of `Class.newInstance`: "**Deprecated.** This method propagates any exception thrown by the nullary constructor, including a checked exception. Use of this method effectively bypasses the compile-time exception checking that would otherwise be performed by the compiler. **The [`Constructor.newInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance(java.lang.Object...)) method avoids this problem** by wrapping any exception thrown by the constructor in a (checked) InvocationTargetException." followed by **example**!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a long standing deprecation of `Class#newInstance`.

```
f_t_c.getConstructor().newInstance();
```

The call above will invoke the normal (in this case: default) constructor,
which allows all handling on construction, like exceptions.